# What is the easiest way to set up a FTP server single signon pointing to /var/www?

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I've tried following numerous tutorials found on the net.  The setup always starts out simple like

`sudo apt-get intstall vsftpd`

and then goes into edditing the `/etc/vsftp.conf` file.  This is where the tutorials fail me becasue most of them either leave the setup for the users `home` directory, or starts getting in the `chroot` setup which appears more complicated than I need.  Some tutorials attempt to explain how to set the defualt path by simply saying "add `local_root=/var/www` in your config file" which I added to the end of the file.  This causes the prompt to get stuck after entering the username.

The problem here is that I don't know if the config directives have specific ordering. And if there is, the tutorials don't go into where it needs to be placed.  I just need a single signon that points to the my `/var/www`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually quite simple - all you need to do is change the home directory definition of that user's entry within /etc/passwd.

Comment: Works like a charm!